# Variables incrementales para sumar

Tags: php, variables

La cosa es que necesito que la variable `$precioinicial` que es donde se guarda el precio total de cada línea de producto sea algo así como `$precioinicial1`, `$precioinicial2`, para después en donde coloco el total sin *IVA*, hacer el sumatorio de esas variables.

Tengo el siguiente fragmento de código:

```html
<table class="table table-bordered">
<thead>
 <th>Cantidad</th>
 <th>Producto</th>
 <th>Precio Unitario</th>
 <th>Total</th>
 <th></th>
</thead>
<?php 
/*
* Apartir de aqui hacemos el recorrido de los productos obtenidos y los reflejamos en una tabla.
*/
foreach($_SESSION["cart"] as $c):
$products = $con->query("select * from product where id=$c[product_id]");
$r = $products->fetch_object();
 ?>
<tr>
<th><?php echo $c["q"];?></th>
 <td><?php echo $r->name;?></td>
 <td><?php echo $r->price; ?> € </td>
 <td><?php $precioinicial = $c["q"]*$r->price;
 echo $precioinicial;?> € </td>
 
 
 
 <td style="width:260px;">
 <?php
 $found = false;
 foreach ($_SESSION["cart"] as $c) { if($c["product_id"]==$r->id){ $found=true; break; }}
 ?>
  <a href="php/delfromcart.php?id=<?php echo $c["product_id"];?>" class="btn btn-danger">Eliminar</a>
 </td>
 </tr>

<?php endforeach; ?>
 <tr>
 <td>
 </td>
 <td>
 </td>
 <td>
 </td>
 <td>
 Total sin IVA<br>
 <?php echo $precioinicial;?> € 
 </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transformá `$precioinicial` en un array:

```
foreach($_SESSION["cart"] as $i => $c):
...
<td><?php $precioinicial[$i] = $c["q"]*$r->price;   echo $precioinicial[$i]; ?> € </td>
```

Y para obtener la suma:

```
<?php echo array_sum($precioinicial); ?> €
```